# SQL Query Issues in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, sql

I searched around and I did not have complete success attempting to create this query to display the results properly.  Suffice to say, I am looking for a little assistance wrapping my head around the structure I can use.  Essentially, i have a table with multiple products (product_list) and another table (product_images) that contains multiple pictures per every one product.  I am trying to pull up only one image for each product and display the one product and one picture together.  This is my code.  Let me know what you think.

```
SELECT `product_list`.*, 
(SELECT * FROM product_images 
WHERE product_list.product_tag = product_images.img_tag LIMIT 1) 

FROM (`product_list`) 
LEFT JOIN `product_images` 
ON `product_list`.`product_tag` = `product_images`.`img_tag` 
WHERE `product_list`.`product_tag` = product_images.img_tag 
AND product_list.name_family = product_images.img_family 
ORDER BY `date` desc LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
    SELECT pl.*, pi.*
    FROM `product_list` pl
    LEFT JOIN `product_images` pi
    ON pl.`product_tag` = pi.`img_tag` 
    AND  pl.name_family = pi.img_family 
    GROUP BY pl.product_id   -- change this to your product_id
    ORDER BY `date` desc 
    LIMIT 10
```

make sure to change this to your product_id

Comment: Not sure why but I seem to be getting the same product more than once but with two different pictures (because the product has more than one picture in the table).

Comment: check my edited answer and change product_id to your product_id,

Comment: That was perfect.  Thanks for the help I spent entirely too much time trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the one image per product tag you can do so

```
SELECT p.*, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
GROUP_CONCAT(pimg.your_image_name_column) ,',',1) `image_name`
FROM `product_list` p
LEFT JOIN `product_images` pimg 
ON p.`product_tag` = pimg.`img_tag` 
WHERE p.`product_tag` = pimg.img_tag 
AND p.name_family = pimg.img_family 
GROUP BY p.`product_tag`
ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 10
```

You can also use `ORDER BY` in `GROUP_CONCAT(pimg.your_image_name_column ORDER BY some_column_from_images_table)`

[Using Active Record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

```
$this->db->select('p.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(pimg.your_image_name_column) ,',',1) `image_name`',FALSE);
$this->db->from('product_list p')
$this->db->join('product_images pimg','p.product_tag = pimg.img_tag','LEFT')
$this->db->where('p.product_tag = pimg.img_tag AND p.name_family = pimg.img_family');
$this->db->group_by("p.product_tag"); 
$this->db->order_by("date", "desc");
$this->db->limit(10);
```